# How to toggle visibility action bar tab navigation?

Tags: android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager

I use Action Bar Sherlock library.

In SherlockFragmentActivity, Make tabs and pager (Swipe + Tab)

```
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("tab1").setTabListener(this));
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("tab2").setTabListener(this));
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("tab3").setTabListener(this));
```

When paging. I change tab.
When tab selected, I change page.

(These works fine.)

And make button to toggle visiblity.

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS); // this force tab index = 0
//or
actionBar.setNavigationMode(NAVIGATION_MODE_DEFAULT);
```

But Setting navigation mode to NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS, 
make tab index = 0 not current tab(pager) index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try storing current tab index to an integer before you call actionBar.setNavigationMode(NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

int index=actionBar.getSelectedNavigationItem();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(NAVIGATION_MODE_DEFAULT);

actionBar.setNavigationMode(NAVIGATION_MODE_DEFAULT);
actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(index);

Comment: I did. But It cause page animaton... if current tab index is 3, And toggle mode, show page animation (1 => 2 => 3)

Comment: Does your setOnPageChangeListener() and setTabListener() does anything other than setting item? Something like incrementing any variable?